# Calling Javascript to make HTML that can be used by different Javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Current situation: 
Have a timesheet that allows the user to enter their leave, TOIL, Sick which totals the hours.Have a table that creates a new row everytime the plus button is pressed. Using the following

**Table Creates & Removes rows**

```
function CreateNewRow(num, str) {
    var intLine = parseInt(document.frmMain.hdnMaxLine.value);
    intLine++;

    var theTable = document.getElementById("tbExp");
    var newRow = theTable.insertRow(theTable.rows.length)
    newRow.id = newRow.uniqueID

    var newCell

    //*** ID Column ***//
    newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
    newCell.id = newCell.uniqueID;
    newCell.setAttribute("className", "css-name");
    newCell.innerHTML = num;

    //*** Column 1 ***//
    newCell = newRow.insertCell(1);
    newCell.id = newCell.uniqueID;
    newCell.setAttribute("className", "css-name");
    //newCell.innerHTML = "<center><INPUT TYPE=\"TEXT\" SIZE=\"10\" NAME=\"Column1_"+intLine+"\"  ID=\"Column1_"+intLine+"\" VALUE=\"\"></center>";
    newCell.innerHTML = str;

    //*** Column 2 ***//
    newCell = newRow.insertCell(2);
    newCell.id = newCell.uniqueID;
    newCell.setAttribute("className", "css-name");
    newCell.innerHTML = "<center><SELECT NAME=\"Column5_"+intLine+"\" ID=\"Column5_"+intLine+"\"></SELECT></center>";

    //*** Column 3 ***//
    newCell = newRow.insertCell(3);
    newCell.id = newCell.uniqueID;
    newCell.setAttribute("className", "css-name");
    newCell.innerHTML = "<center><INPUT TYPE=\"TEXT\" SIZE=\"5\" NAME=\"Column4_" + intLine + "\"  ID=\"Column4_" + intLine + "\" VALUE=\"\"></center>";


    //*** Create Option ***//
    CreateSelectOption("Column5_" + intLine)
    document.frmMain.hdnMaxLine.value = intLine;
}

function RemoveRow() {
    intLine = parseInt(document.frmMain.hdnMaxLine.value);
    if(parseInt(intLine) > 0) {
        theTable = document.getElementById("tbExp");
        theTableBody = theTable.tBodies[0];
        theTableBody.deleteRow(intLine);
        intLine--;
        document.frmMain.hdnMaxLine.value = intLine;
    }
}
```

**Timesheet.js**

```
function updateTotal()
{
  var total = 0;
  $(".dayinput").map( function() { total += $(this).val() * 8; } );
  $(".hourinput").map( function() { total += $(this).val() * 1; } );
  $("#total").val( total );

  if( total >= 40 )
  {
    $("#total").removeClass( "total_low" );
    $("#total").addClass( "total_ok" );
  }
  else
  {
    $("#total").removeClass( "total_ok" );
    $("#total").addClass( "total_low" );
  }
}

function validateUpdateTotal()
{
  if( ($(this).val()-0) != $(this).val() )
  {
    alert( "Invalid number" );
    $(this).val( "" );
  }
  else
    updateTotal();
}
function initPage()
{
  $("#project_select").val("");
  $("#task_select").val("");
  $(".hourinput").val("");
  $(".dayinput").val("");
  updateTotal();
}
$(".dayinput").change( validateUpdateTotal );
$(".hourinput").change( validateUpdateTotal );

$(document).ready( initPage );
```

**HTML**

```
<fieldset>

<div class="left">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Leave</td>
            <td><input class="dayinput" type="text" name="Leave"></td>
        </t>
        <tr>
            <td>TOIL</td>
            <td><input class="dayinput" type="text" name="TOIL"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sick</td>
            <td><input class="dayinput" type="text" name="Sick"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td><input id="total" class="total_low" type="text" value="0" disabled="">
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>

    <div class="right">

    <b>Projects this week</b><div class = "right"><input name="btnDel" type="button" id="btnDel" value="-" onClick="RemoveRow();"></div>

    <ul id="task_list">
        <form name="frmMain" method="post">
        <table width="470" border="1" id="tbExp">
          <tr>
            <td><div align="center">No.</div></td>
            <td><div align="center">Project </div></td>
            <td><div align="center">Task </div></td>
            <td><div align="center">Hours </div></td>
            <td><div align="center"></div></td> 
          </tr>
        </table>

        <input type="hidden" name="hdnMaxLine" value="0">
        </form>
    </ul>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

I am now trying to use the InnerHTML function to make a HTML textbox that can be used by the timesheet.js table. So that when the user enters their hours it updates both tables.

I tried the following `newCell.innerHTML = "<center><INPUT TYPE=\"TEXT\" SIZE=\"5\" NAME=\"HOURINPUT\" CLASS=\"hourinput\"></center>;`
This did not work for me, what is it that I need to do in order to get this working?

The image shown explains what I am trying to do

Updated Image after changes:

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is a problem but the `<center>` tag is so deprecated.

Comment: Its not the center tag. I've <INPUT TYPE=\"TEXT\" SIZE=\"5\" NAME=\"HOURINPUT\" CLASS=\"hourinput\"> and it still does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//*** Column 3 ***//
newCell = newRow.insertCell(3);
newCell.id = newCell.uniqueID;
newCell.setAttribute("className", "css-name");
newCell.innerHTML = "<center><INPUT CLASS=\"hourinput\" TYPE=\"TEXT\" SIZE=\"5\" NAME=\"Column4_" + intLine + "\"  ID=\"Column4_" + intLine + "\" VALUE=\"\"></center>";
```

Also try changing

```
$(".hourinput").change( validateUpdateTotal );
```

to

```
$(".hourinput").bind('change', validateUpdateTotal);
```

Comment: So are you saying that, in the new example, the wages for the hours you entered are not being added to the total?

Comment: Aha! You've finally pinpointed the problem. Good work. See above

Comment: Great, it works however in order to get the total to calculate you need to enter values for sick, toil and leave. I think this has something to do with my click function. Would you agree?

Comment: Right, but you said that function was fine before?

Comment: it is fine... for the sick, leave, hours but now with the method you gave me, it still requires me to input something in the sick, leave, toil and click away before it updates what ive done in the hours field.